# Why am I getting ReferenceError: Response is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node.js with express. I am trying to set up a basic server, but have no idea why I am getting a response error.

```
var http = require('http');

var myServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    response.write('Hello World');
    response.end();
});

myServer.listen(3000);
```

Comment: change `response` to `res`  as defined by `function(req,res)`

Comment: Got it, so I don't have to follow any pre-ordained methods? I can set up my own arguments as long as it follows same structure inside of code?

Comment: Yeah that's right. You could name it `bob` for example :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
function(req,res)
```

is supposed to be

```
function(req, response) {
```

You don't have a variable named `response` in the scope of the callback. That is the reason for the `reference error`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. so I can use any variable both inside of the function argument, and inside of the scope so long as they match? I always thought that function(req,res) was a built in method from the 'http' module.

Comment: @EdwardK. You could use any variable name as long as it matches the function arguments. `function(aa, bb) {
bb.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
bb.write('Hello World');
bb.end();

}` will work to.

Comment: @EdwardK.—values are passed by order, not name, so the callee can assign whatever names it wants.